# AVR - GNU AS - Force end of line after assembler directive in preprocessor macro

Tags: avr, preprocessor, gnu-assembler

Try to write a bare-metal bootloader (without `avr-libc`) for a Microchip AVR microcontroller. I will use a own startup code for initialize the `.bss` and `.data` section.

I use following macros (defines) imported from my other bare-metal projects:
*asm.h*

```
#define _EXPORT_SYMBOL_ASM(name) \
        .global name ; \
        name:

/* Entry (Never returns) */
#define ENTRY(name) \
        _EXPORT_SYMBOL_ASM(name)
```

The usage in an assembly file:
*start.S*

```
#include "asm.h"

ENTRY(_start)
    /* Some assembly code */
```

The macro `ENTRY()` works on the architectures *AArch32*, *AArch64*, *x86* and *AMD64*. But on AVR architecture the semicolon seems to be interpreted as **comment**.

Is there a way in `avr-as` to put multiple assembler directives on the same line?

Comment: Certainly. In avr-as you include a NewLine character to force an end of line after an assembler directive.  What is the question? If you are going to use an ifdef to modify your c macro preprocessor #defines to 'force an end of line', why not use an ifdef to create a multiline AVR macro definition instead? If you aren't planning to ifdef AVR, what do you have in minde? What is the question?

Comment: @david The question might be wrong formulated. But now after a long search, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In the AVR implementation from GAS, the semicolon is indeed interpreted as comment.

> 9.4.2.1 Special Characters
>
> The presence of a ‘;’ anywhere on a line indicates the start of a
> comment that extends to the end of that line.
>
> If a ‘#’ appears as the first character of a line, the whole line is
> treated as a comment, but in this case the line can also be a logical
> line number directive (see Comments) or a preprocessor control command
> (see Preprocessing).
>
> The ‘$’ character can be used instead of a newline to separate
> statements.

[Source for this quote](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/binutils-stable/html/as/as.html#AVR_002dDependent)

The following works now:

```
#define _EXPORT_SYMBOL_ASM(name) \
        .global name $ \
        name:
```